# vuejs program doesnt give desired output

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vuejs code as below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vue2 Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2" ></script>
  </head>
<body>
<div id="app-4">
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      {{ todo.text }}
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>

<script>
var app4 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-4',
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: 'Learn JavaScript' },
      { text: 'Learn Vue' },
      { text: 'Build something awesome' }
    ]
  }
</script>
</body>
```

The output is expected to show the list of todos
But the program shows simply as below

```
1.{{ todo.text }}
```

How can I get the correct output. What is the error here?

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong in your code. Are you using any tool for hot reloading, like `live-server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vue2 Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app-4">
      <ol>
        <li v-for="todo in todos">
          {{ todo.text }}
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>

<script>
var app4 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-4',
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: 'Learn JavaScript' },
      { text: 'Learn Vue' },
      { text: 'Build something awesome' }
    ]
  }
})
</script>
</body>
```

---

Open with `npx serve .` or just an `index.html` file in your browser.

Comment: Is not the same code in the question?

Comment: @Álvaro nope, the object wasn't closed (check again).

Comment: Yup. You're right. `Vue instance` wasn't closed. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your data block isn't correct

```
<template>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo">
      {{ todo.text }}
    </li>
  </ol>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      todos: [
        { text: "Learn JavaScript" },
        { text: "Learn Vue" },
        { text: "Build something awesome" },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: If that were the problem there would be a mistake about it, wouldn't there? It wouldn't be able to read the `todos` variable in the template.